# Is this Java Json (Gson) code to check correct response is not too redundant?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have Json parser class which was written by someone else. I smell that it is something bad with this checker method:

```
    public boolean isCorrectResponse() {
    try {
        if (localResponse != null) {
            JSONObject jResponse = new JSONObject(localResponse);
            if (jResponse.get("result") instanceof JSONObject) { 
                JSONObject jResult = jResponse.getJSONObject("result");
                if (jResult.get("error") instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONObject jError = jResult.getJSONArray("error").getJSONObject(0);
                    if (!jError.toString().equals("")) {
                        String errorMsg = jError.getString("msg");
                        String errorCode = jError.getString("code");
                        showErrorMessage(errorCode + "; " + errorMsg);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        L.e("ERROR: on isCorrectResponse method!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //return false; //Added myself Google Json should throw error shouldn't it??? Which means response was wrong???
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Shouldn't error be thrown in first attempt to create 
`JSONObject jResponse = new JSONObject(localResponse);`
 and everything would be solved instantly (I need only to return false)? Is these additional checks in try body are needed at all? 
I'm using Google Gson library to parse Json and developing for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse each tag of the JSON is a high work and it's not a very good idea check if (jResponse.get("result") instanceof JSONObject)

Better use

```
 JSONObject result =jResponse.get("result") instanceof JSONObject)
 if (result == null) return false;
```

Anyway if you add a catch to NullPointerException you can avoid this if. When the result is null, when you try to parse the next tag the app will throw an exception

Comment: OK, I see that to check everything is bad idea. But does simple jResponse.get("result") check and catch error is enough?

Comment: Sorry i never use GSON parser but i think it's very easy to test it, is't it?

Comment: Yes Indeed. It works nice. At least in my test cases it seems that it had no problems.